# Why are the faces skipped?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

Blender 2.81a MacOS

[image: Face selection combining faces together]

I tried lifting the vertices and this is what I got.
[image: this vertex is connected to the faces(I've used the same method for creating both the vertices)]
[image: vertex not connected to the faces]

I started modelling with a plane, got rid of the two vertices and formed this mesh, by extruding, subdividing and joining them.

I'd love to know where I got wrong so that I can model better in the future.

Comment: Your first gif clearly shows that the faces in the problematic area aren't connected to the vertices you're moving. This can be seen by the little square that is in the middle of every face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first gif shows that you have faces which aren't properly connected to the surrounding vertices. This can be seen because the face center is marked with a little black square.

[image: Bad faces]

The top face is an ngon that consists of eight vertices (marked in blue) and the center vertex isn't part of it.

[image: Vertices that form ngon]

In order to fix this, switch to face select mode (either by clicking on the icon or using the <kbd>3</kbd> shortcut in Blender 2.8x), select the top face and delete it (<kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces*).

[image: Face select mode]

[image: Select top face]

Switch back to vertex select mode and select four vertices that are supposed to form a face. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face and repeat this step with the next four vertices until you have created all four faces.

[image: Face created]
[image: Fixed top]

The two faces on the side are ngons as well and consist of six vertices each. The vertex you're moving in the second gif is part of both faces, but the two horizontal edges aren't.

Switch to face select mode and select both problematic faces. Then press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces Only*, which will remove the faces but keep the vertical edge.

[image: Select side faces]

Once the side faces are deleted, switch to vertex select mode, select four vertices and create a face with <kbd>F</kbd>. Repeat this step until you've created all four faces.

[image: Add face to side]

[image: Fixed topology]